# Reopen an existing file descriptor with open("/dev/fd/n", mode)

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, systems-programming

I am studying in System Programming.

If we call open("/dev/fd/n", mode), we duplicate the n-th file descriptor and assign to a new file descriptor.

However, the mode we specify needs to be the subset of the referenced file (/dev/fd/n), and, I was wondering how is this working.

---

Does this create a new entry in the open file table?

1. If it does, why should the mode be a subset of /dev/fd/n's file status flag?
2. If not, how could I have two different file descriptor pointing to the same entry in file entry table with different file status flag?

Comment: Opening a new file creates a new entry in the file table.  Period.  Closing the file frees the fd# to be re-used for a subsequent file (at least on some OS's), but it's always a new, different file entry.  "mode" doesn't really have much of anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

When we open `/dev/fd/n`, we are *not* "duplicating" a file descriptor. We are opening a brand new file.

You may be confusing this with using `dup`. Since we know the binary value of `n`, we could do: `int fdn = dup(n);`. That *would* share things.

But, that is *not* what we're doing.

`/dev/fd` is a *symlink* to `/proc/self/fd`. If we do `ls -l /proc/self/fd > /tmp/out`, we'll get something like:

```
total 0
lrwx------. 1 cae cae 64 Nov  7 00:16 0 -> /dev/pts/2
l-wx------. 1 cae cae 64 Nov  7 00:16 1 -> /tmp/out
lrwx------. 1 cae cae 64 Nov  7 00:16 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------. 1 cae cae 64 Nov  7 00:16 3 -> /proc/35153/fd
```

If we do:

```
fd = open("/proc/self/0",O_WRONLY);
```

this is *identical* to doing:

```
fd2 = open("/dev/pts/2",O_WRONLY);
```

`fd` and `fd2` do *not* share any flags/modes, etc. They are completely separate. Nor do they have any common flags/modes with fd 0.

Note that I deliberately specified `/proc/self/0` [which is open for *reading*] and, yet, we opened it for *writing*.

It does *not* care about [nor use] the original descriptors flags, etc. Once again, it is just a "double level" *symlink* to the full path of the final *target* file: `/dev/pts/2`

It is the *file* permissions of the target file that dictate whether a given `open` is allowed (e.g. if the permissions were 0444, and we tried to open with `O_WRONLY`, that would return `EPERM`).

This would be no different than if we had a directory that looked like:

```
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 cae cae 0 Nov  7 00:29 a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 cae cae 1 Nov  7 00:29 b -> a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 cae cae 1 Nov  7 00:29 c -> a
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 cae cae 1 Nov  7 00:29 d -> c
```

We could do:

```
int fd1 = open("a",O_RDONLY);
int fd2 = open("b",O_WRONLY);
int fd3 = open("c",O_WRONLY);
int fd4 = open("d",O_WRONLY);
```

Those four file descriptors don't share anything. But, they are four separate streams to the same file. So, if we write to any of `fd2`, `fd3`, or `fd4`. Then, read from `fd1` and we'll see the effect.